# Python 3 arbitrary base converter and base36 encoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, converting

This is a script that can convert any numerical value to any arbitrary radix representation and back, well, technically it can convert a number to any base, but because the output is a string representation with each a character as a digit, and possible digits are 10 Arabic numerals plus 26 basic Latin (lowercase) letters, the base can only be an integer from 2 to 36 (including both ends).

The possible digits are 0..9 + a..z, just like how hexadecimal orders them, I used bit shifting to convert to and from a base that is a power of two, and divmod for every other base. In my testing, bit-shifting is actually a bit slower than divmoding, I don't know why.

I have written a function that converts a decimal number to a base between 2 and 36, and another function that converts a number from a base between 2 and 36 to decimal, both functions validate the possibility of conversion before the actual conversion.

I have also written three sets of function that converts binary data to and from base-36.

The first set encode and decode the hexadecimal value of the binary data as a whole, rather than individual bytes, so the result can be more compact.

The second set encode and decode each character as two base-36 bits, with the highest possible two-bit being `zz` which in decimal is 1295 or (36 ^ 2) - 1, as such it can be accurate up to `\u050f` or `ԏ`, but extended ASCII has only 256 code points the second set is sufficient for non-UNICODE characters.

The third set encode and decode each byte as two base-36 bits, it can therefore represent any UNICODE code point, and its output is same as the second set for code points below 1296.

The code:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import digits

def log2(n):
    return n.bit_length() - 1

def power_of_2(n):
    return (n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0

glyphs = digits + ascii_lowercase

def parser(s, base):
    sep = ','
    if base == 60:
        sep = ':'
    elif base == 256:
        sep = '.'
    if 2 <= base <= 36:
        return [glyphs.index(i) for i in s]
    return s.split(sep)

def to_base(num, base):
    if base < 2 or not isinstance(base, int):
        return
    
    sep = ','
    if base == 60:
        sep = ':'
    elif base == 256:
        sep = '.'
    
    if power_of_2(base):
        l = log2(base)
        powers = range(num.bit_length() // l + (num.bit_length() % l != 0))
        places = [(num >> l * i) % base for i in powers]
    
    else:
        if num == 0:
            return ('0', base)
        
        places = []
        while num:
            n, p = divmod(num, base)
            places.append(p)
            num = n
    if base > 36:
        return (sep.join(map(str, reversed(places))), base)
    return (''.join([glyphs[p] for p in reversed(places)]), base)

def from_base(s, base):
    if base < 2 or not isinstance(base, int):
        return
    
    sep = ','
    if base == 60:
        sep = ':'
    elif base == 256:
        sep = '.'
    
    if base <= 36:
        for i in s:
            if glyphs.index(i) >= base:
                return
    
    else:
        for i in s.split(sep):
            if int(i) >= base:
                return
    
    places = parser(s, base)
    
    if power_of_2(base):
        l = log2(base)
        return sum([int(n) << l * p for p, n in enumerate(reversed(places))])
    
    powers = reversed([base ** i for i in range(len(places))])
    return sum(int(a) * b for a, b in zip(places, powers))

def b36encode(s):
    msg = s.encode('utf8').hex()
    n = int(msg, 16)
    return to_base(n, 36)[0]

def b36decode(m):
    n = from_base(m, 36)
    h = hex(n).lstrip('0x')
    return bytes.fromhex(h).decode('utf8')

def b36_encode(s):
    msg = [ord(i) for i in s]
    return ''.join([to_base(n, 36)[0].zfill(2) for n in msg])

def b36_decode(m):
    s = [from_base(n, 36) for n in [m[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(m), 2)]]
    return ''.join(chr(n) for n in s)

def base36_encode(s):
    msg = s.encode('utf8')
    return ''.join([to_base(n, 36)[0] for n in msg])

def base36_decode(m):
    s = [from_base(n, 36) for n in [m[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(m), 2)]]
    return bytearray(s).decode('utf8')
```

Sample usage:

```
In [282]: to_base(16777215, 3)
Out[282]: ('1011120101000100', 3)

In [283]: from_base(*to_base(16777215, 3))
Out[283]: 16777215

In [284]: to_base(2**32-1, 3)
Out[284]: ('102002022201221111210', 3)

In [285]: from_base(*to_base(2**32-1, 3))
Out[285]: 4294967295

In [286]: from_base(*to_base(2**64-1, 36))
Out[286]: 18446744073709551615

In [287]: to_base(2**64-1, 36)
Out[287]: ('3w5e11264sgsf', 36)

In [288]: to_base(46610, 16)
Out[288]: ('b612', 16)

In [289]: to_base(54, 13)
Out[289]: ('42', 13)

In [290]: from_base('zzz', 36)
Out[290]: 46655

In [291]: from_base('computer', 36)
Out[291]: 993986429283

In [292]: to_base(from_base('computer', 36),36)
Out[292]: ('computer', 36)

In [293]: '\u1800'
Out[293]: '᠀'

In [294]: b36encode('whoami')
Out[294]: '1ajdznl1ex'

In [295]: b36decode(b36encode('whoami'))
Out[295]: 'whoami'

In [296]: b36decode(b36encode('\u1800\u1800\u1800'))
Out[296]: '᠀᠀᠀'

In [297]: base36_decode(base36_encode('\u1800\u1800\u1800'))
Out[297]: '᠀᠀᠀'
```

What improvement can be made to my code?

---

Update:

I have improved representation scheme to make it able to represent numbers in any base.

For bases bigger than 36, the resultant string is a mixed radix representation, with the digits represented in their decimal form instead of having a single character representing its value, and a separator delimit the digits.

The separator is determined by the base, for base 60 the separator is a colon (`:`), similar to how time is represented, for base 256 the separator is a dot (`.`), similar to how IPv4 addresses are represented, and a comma (`,`) for any other base.

I have considered using the Greek alphabet after Latin alphabet (after Arabic numerals) to make single character notation representation form able to represent numbers in base-60, however many Greek letters and Latin letters are homoglyphs I abandoned the idea to avoid ambiguity.

Examples:

```
In [52]: to_base(16777216,64)
Out[52]: ('1,0,0,0,0', 64)

In [53]: to_base(16777215,64)
Out[53]: ('63,63,63,63', 64)

In [54]: to_base(33554431,64)
Out[54]: ('1,63,63,63,63', 64)

In [55]: to_base(86399,60)
Out[55]: ('23:59:59', 60)

In [56]: to_base(86399,365)
Out[56]: ('236,259', 365)

In [57]: to_base(2**32-1,256)
Out[57]: ('255.255.255.255', 256)
```

Comment: You realize that `from_base` can be entirely replaced with a call to `int()`, right?

Comment: @Reinderien Of course I do realize `from_base` can be entirely replaced with a call to `int`, I even make it accept the same types of positional arguments in the same order, while using `int` is far more performant than `from_base`, using `int` doesn't demonstrate that I know how to do the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to have good code, most of this shouldn't exist and you should make better use of built-ins, but it seems like that isn't your goal.

If your goal is to demonstrate that you know how to write functions equivalent to the built-ins, you haven't quite hit your mark, because the built-ins are able to deal with negative numbers and your functions are not.

As for a review laundry-list:

- You need PEP484 type hints
- `glyphs` should be capitalized since it's a global constant
- You have a bunch of verbatim-repeated code, such as your selection of separators, for which you should factor out functions
- `parser` looks up a separator even when it doesn't need one. Only look up the separator if base is greater than 36.
- Do not `return` on failure; `raise` instead.
- There is no value in returning the base as a second tuple element from `to_base`; the caller knows what base it's going to be.
- `lstrip('0x')` does not do what you think it does. Hint: what is `'xxx000xxx'.lstrip('0x')` ? Use `removeprefix` instead.
- More repeated code in the comprehensions for your `b36_decode` and `base36_decode` functions that need to be factored out.
- Convert your sample usage into unit tests.

### Suggested

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import digits
from typing import List, Iterable

GLYPHS = digits + ascii_lowercase


def log2(n: int) -> int:
    return n.bit_length() - 1


def power_of_2(n: int) -> bool:
    return (n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0


def sep_for_base(base: int) -> str:
    return {
        60: ':',
        256: '.',
    }.get(base, ',')


def parser(s: str, base: int) -> List[int]:
    if 2 <= base <= 36:
        return [GLYPHS.index(i) for i in s]

    return s.split(sep_for_base(base))


def to_base(num: int, base: int) -> str:
    if base < 2 or not isinstance(base, int):
        raise ValueError()

    if power_of_2(base):
        l = log2(base)
        powers = range(num.bit_length() // l + (num.bit_length() % l != 0))
        places = [(num >> l * i) % base for i in powers]

    else:
        if num == 0:
            return '0'

        places = []
        while num:
            n, p = divmod(num, base)
            places.append(p)
            num = n

    if base > 36:
        sep = sep_for_base(base)
        return sep.join(map(str, reversed(places)))

    return ''.join([GLYPHS[p] for p in reversed(places)])


def from_base(s: str, base: int) -> int:
    if base < 2 or not isinstance(base, int):
        raise ValueError()

    if base <= 36:
        for i in s:
            if GLYPHS.index(i) >= base:
                raise ValueError()

    else:
        sep = sep_for_base(base)
        for i in s.split(sep):
            if int(i) >= base:
                raise ValueError()

    places = parser(s, base)

    if power_of_2(base):
        l = log2(base)
        return sum([int(n) << l * p for p, n in enumerate(reversed(places))])

    powers = reversed([base ** i for i in range(len(places))])
    return sum(int(a) * b for a, b in zip(places, powers))


def b36encode(s: str) -> str:
    msg = s.encode('utf8').hex()
    n = int(msg, 16)
    return to_base(n, 36)


def b36decode(m: str) -> str:
    n = from_base(m, 36)
    h = hex(n).removeprefix('0x')
    return bytes.fromhex(h).decode('utf8')


def b36_encode(s: str) -> str:
    msg = [ord(i) for i in s]
    return ''.join([to_base(n, 36).zfill(2) for n in msg])


def b36_digits(m: str) -> Iterable[int]:
    for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
        n = m[i:i+2]
        yield from_base(n, 36)


def b36_decode(m) -> str:
    s = b36_digits(m)
    return ''.join(chr(n) for n in s)


def base36_encode(s: str) -> str:
    msg = s.encode('utf8')
    return ''.join([to_base(n, 36) for n in msg])


def base36_decode(m: str) -> str:
    s = b36_digits(m)
    return bytearray(s).decode('utf8')


def assert_from_base(s: str, base: int, exp: int) -> None:
    assert int(s, base) == exp
    assert from_base(s, base) == exp


def round_trip(x: int, base: int, s: str) -> None:
    s_actual = to_base(x, base)
    assert s == s_actual
    assert_from_base(s, base, x)


def test() -> None:
    round_trip(2**24-1, 3, '1011120101000100')
    round_trip(2**32-1, 3, '102002022201221111210')
    round_trip(2**64-1, 36, '3w5e11264sgsf')

    assert to_base(46610, 16) == 'b612'

    assert to_base(54, 13) == '42'

    assert_from_base('zzz', 36, 46655)

    round_trip(993986429283, 36, 'computer')

    assert b36encode('whoami') == '1ajdznl1ex'
    assert b36decode('1ajdznl1ex') == 'whoami'

    assert '᠀᠀᠀' == '\u1800\u1800\u1800'
    assert b36encode('᠀᠀᠀') == 'oedjywcl6i78g0'
    assert b36decode('oedjywcl6i78g0') == '᠀᠀᠀'
    assert base36_encode('᠀᠀᠀') == '694g3k694g3k694g3k'
    assert base36_decode('694g3k694g3k694g3k') == '᠀᠀᠀'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: nit: "def parser" should be "def parse"